# Limit involving sinus to show resonance-behavior

Tags: analysis, limits

I got the following term: 
$$ - \frac{\omega}{\mu^2 - \omega^2} \frac{1}{\mu} \sin(\mu t) + \frac{1}{\mu^2 - \omega^2} \sin(\omega t),$$
with $t, \mu \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\mu > 0$ and i'm interested what happens, if you take the limit $\omega \to \mu$.

(The background to this term is that $\mu^2$ are eigenfrequencies of a sytem and $\omega$ is a frequency of an extern force to the system. The solution of the system involves this term and i basically want to show resonance, i.e. the solution isn't bounded anymore in time $t$ if the extern force oscillates at the same frequency as $\mu$.)

At first sight i thought that the terms will nullify, because with $\omega \approx \mu$ the terms should be close to each other with different signs, but numerically i found out that the difference behaves like "$t \sin(t)$", i.e. oscillates and gets very large.

Does anyone with more analytically background has a proof or way to approach showing the limit of this term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

$$\frac{\sin\omega t-\frac\omega\mu\sin\mu t}{\mu^2-\omega^2}$$

Check that l'Hospital's conditions are fulfilled when $\;\omega\to\mu\;$ (why?), so

$$\lim_{\omega\to\mu}\frac{\sin\omega t-\frac\omega\mu\sin\mu t}{\mu^2-\omega^2}=\lim_{\omega\to\mu}\frac{t\cos\omega t-\frac1\mu\sin\mu t}{-2\omega}=-\frac{t\cos\mu t-\frac1\mu\sin\mu t}{2\mu}$$